# Query for find Nth maximum value in Mysql

Tags: mysql

How do I write a query to find the *N*<sup>th</sup> maximum value in MySQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT (n-1), 1
```

Have a look at http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm for reading up on LIMIT on SQL:

> ***Definition:*** Limit is used to limit your MySQL query results to those that fall within a specified range. You can use it to show the first X number of results, or to show a range from X - Y results. It is phrased as Limit X, Y and included at the end of your query. **X is the starting point (remember the first record is 0) and Y is the duration (how many records to display)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date FROM t1 WHERE date =(
SELECT DISTINCT(date ) FROM t1 AS SSELWS  WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(date))-1 FROM t1 )=
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(date ))+1 FROM t1 AS s2 WHERE SSELWS.date >s2.date ORDER BY s2.date ASC
)  ORDER BY SSELWS.date ASC)
```

Answer (score 0):

---

> Select * from world w1  where (N-1) = (Select
>   Count(distinct(population)) from world w2  where w2.population >
>   w1.population)

---

Answer (score -3):

The Maximum Value for a Column:

SELECT MAX([column_name]) AS [alias] FROM [table_name];